# PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php

```php
  if($context == "checkoutProgress") {

            $params["shipping"] = "";
            $shipping_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
            $shipping_id = explode(":",$shipping_id)[0];
            if(isset(WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods()[$shipping_id])) {
                $params["shipping"] = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods()[$shipping_id]->method_title;
            }
```

Comment: That error message should include a line number to isolate the problem. Regardless, all of your usages of arrays seem to be from function/method calls. One of them is returning null.

Comment: Please post the full error message and PHP version. Please try to use `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0] : ''`. But note that this is just my guess.